# Búsqueda automática al escribir, ya genera un "select/options" no me funciona

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hermandad, tengo un código donde quiero generar una lista (select/option) como resultados de mi búsqueda, a medida que la persona teclee, en seguida estará haciendo la búsqueda.
Tengo el código, pero este no se activa, no puedo encontrar dónde lo estoy haciendo mal.
Agradezco que alguien pueda observar los detalles.
Gracias.

esa es la parte HTML, aqui es donde quero que inserte la palabra a buscar y en el mismo local ya genere la lista de resultados

```html
     <section><label>Buscar cliente</label>
        <form method="GET" action="">
       <input type="text" id="termo_busca" name="termo_busca" />
        <select id="lista" onclick="if( $('#lista').html() == '' ){alert('Sem resultados carregados.');}"></select>
                        </form>
                    </section>
```

esa es la parte PHP, donde busco en dos colunas (nombre y sobrenome):

```
    <?php
           session_start(); 
       include("../conecta.php");  
if((isset($_GET['keyword']))){
    $nome = htmlspecialchars($_GET['keyword']);
    $busca = "SELECT id_cliente, nome_cliente, sobrenome_cliente FROM Clientes
        WHERE (`nome_cliente` LIKE '%".$nome."%') OR (`sobrenome_cliente` LIKE '%".$nome."%')" or die(mysql_error());
    $resultado_busca = mysqli_query($con, $busca);
    while($row = $resultado_busca->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $nome_cliente = $row['nome_cliente'];
        $sobrenome_cliente = $row['sobrenome_cliente'];
        $id_cliente = $row['id_cliente'];
       
       $lista = "<option value='$id_cliente'>$nome_cliente  $sobrenome_cliente</option>";
        echo $lista;
       
 }
    
}
       ?>
```

la parte JS, donde entiendo meno, no sé se estoy haciendo bien, pero deberia a cada milesegundo hacer la busqueda y generar los resultados:

```js
                   var cache = {};
    
               $(document).ready(function() {
                   addKeyupEvent($('#termo_busca'));
               }   
    
               function addKeyupEvent(element) {
                   element.keyup(function(e) {
                       var keyword = $(this).val();
                       clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
    
                       if (e.keyCode == 13)
                updateListData(search(keyword, true));
                       else
                $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
                    updateListData(search(keyword));
                }, 500));
                   });
               }
    
    function search(keyword, force) {
        if (!force && keyword.length < 4) 
            return '';
    
        if(cache.hasOwnProperty(keyword))
            return cache[keyword];
    
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  'ativos/search.php',
            async: false,
            data: {
               nome: keyword
            },
            success: function(data) {
               cache[keyword] = data;
               return data;
            },
            error: function() {
                throw new Error('Error occured');
                       }
                   });
               }
    
               function updateListData(data) {
                    $('#lista').html(data);
               }
```

Comment: Quizá usar un ***datalist*** se adapte mejor a lo que quieres hacer.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Comment: Voy probar, aúnque no estoy seguro se la busqueda ocurri... no me funciona

Comment: Me queda mucho mejor y creo que es la mejor estructura. Pero todavia no me funciona la busqueda

Comment: ¿Algún error en la consola del navegador o del lado del servidor?